# Accessibility: Is it necessary to mark disabled date/month with ARIA-DISABLED='TRUE' when user can't select disabled date in Date Picker

Tags: jquery-ui, accessibility, datetimepicker

I am working on Web Accessibility. Our client test the site with web accessibility expert and give us a manual that the site needs to be fixed or modified.

On Date Picker, expert comments as follows

> Use ARIA roles and properties to define the date picker.
>   See Appendix A, "Accessible date picker requirements" for detailed information.
>
> NOTE:  If a month or date is disabled, user aria-disabled="true" on the active element to indicate the disabled state.

Here is the code example

```
<lable>
   Date:
  <input id="dp" type="text" />
</lable>

/** JS CODE **/
$(function() {

  $('#dp, #dp1').datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date()
  });

});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q68jyebL/17/

I am using jQuery Date Picker. Keyboard user can not move the cursor before the `minDate`. For example, if the `minDate` is set to today keyboard user can not select or move the cursor before today. Now is it necessary to mark the previous day(that are disabled) with `aria-disabled = 'true'` ?

My understanding is if the user are not allow to move before the `minDate` it makes no sense to mark the disabled date with `aria-disabled`.

Any kind of suggestion appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'yes'.  The unselectable dates must have `aria-disabled='true'`.

While you are correct that the unselectable dates are not focusable using the keyboard, a screen reader user **can** navigate to those dates using screen reader shortcut keys.  Since the month is a `<table>`, a screen reader user can use ctrl+alt+arrowkey to navigate around the table as if it were a spreadsheet.  The visual focus is not moving while using the screen reader shortcut key, but the screen reader will read the data in the table cell.  It looks like jquery is using a style sheet (`class='ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled'`) to visually make the unselectable dates look different from regular dates, but screen readers don't know the intent of style sheets.  You need to tell the screen reader that the cell is disabled via `aria-disabled='true'`.

This is what the generated html should look like for the disabled dates:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled" aria-disabled="true">
  <span class="ui-state-default">4</span>
</td>
```

I don't know how much control you have over the generated jquery date picker and whether you can inject `aria-diabled='true'` into it.  If you do have some control, there's another change you should make too.  The table headers just have 'su', 'mo', tu', etc for the days of the week.  A screen reader is just going to read that text as is.  You should have screen reader friendly text such as 'sunday', 'monday', tuesday', etc.  There **is** a `title` property on each table header but the title is not going to be read.  You should have two pieces of text for each table header cell.  A visible label that is hidden from screen readers ('su', 'mo', 'tu') and a visually hidden label that is available to screen readers ('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday').

The current html that jquery generates looks like this:

```
<th>
  <span title="Monday">Mo</span>
</th>
```

What you want is:

```
<th>
  <span aria-hidden='true'>Mo</span>
  <span class='visually-hidden'>Monday</span>
</th>
```

The `visually-hidden` class should be defined in Appendix A of your report, near the beginning of the Appendix (if I recognize the style of the report correctly).  For those reading this answer that don't have the report, you can see [WebAIM's guidance](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) on hiding content and the [not-yet-approved W3C article](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/fundamentals/hiding/) on hiding content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked into the jQuery Date Picker API. Nothing found helpful. I have to manually manipulate the Date Picker generated HTML code. But is there any Date Picker that will be compliance with WCG 2.0 spec ?

Comment: do a google search for "accessible datepicker" and you'll get 5 good ones at the top of the results.